# What is a suitable equivalent to 2N5459 JFET?

Tags: analog, audio, component-selection, jfet

I am attempting to build an audio limiter circuit which has a JFET as part of the BOM. This JFET is obsolete and no longer manufacturered. Can someone recommend an equivalent JFET or a way of identifying one?

The component is the 2N5459 JFET

Comment: Post the limiter circuit here. It's hard to know what's important without that. With it, we may be able to suggest the important criteria to search out.

Answer (score 1):

Going back to National Semiconductor's "Discrete Databook" (1978 edition) we can see the 2N5459 listed as a "Process 55" transistor : that gives the mask pattern, specifications, and a list of all parts made to Process 55.

(Very useful book by the way; and there is a PDF scan of it online somewhere)

This list is:
TO18  (Case 2)  : 2N3436, 2N3437, 2N3438

TO-72 (Case 25) : 2N3821, 2N3822, 2N3824, 2N4220, 2N4220A, 2N4221, 2N4221A, 2N5358, 2N5359, 2N5360, 2N5361, 2N5362, 2N5363, 2N5364,

TO-92 (Case 72) : 2N5457, 2N5458, 2N5459, MPF103, MPF104, MPF105, MPF108, MPF109, MPF112, PN4220, PN4221, PN4222,

Hopefully you can find one of these...

The MPF102 is listed as Process 50, better at UHF, but half the transconductance of Process 55.

The 2N5457's presence here suggests that the MMBF5457 in another answer may be a Process 55 transistor in a different package (not available in 1978!) and makes me wonder if there's a MMBF5459 which would be a direct replacement.

Where there's a series of numbers, the individual datasheets usually bin them by different threshold voltage, transconductance, or max rated voltage.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct the part is listed as obsolete but I found it is still available online from several sources. They were in the range of $2.60 to $5.00. This may be the best solution if you are only building a few. Here are some cross reference parts that should work however the pinouts may not be the same: MPF102,2SK162,  2N5458,  NTE312, 2N3819,2N5457, 2N5638, 2N5640.

Answer (score 0):

JFETs like that are becoming harder to source, I would look closely at the data sheet of the MMBF5457 and see if it would fit the bill, Onsemi show it as currently active, if you can't source it an MMBFJ201 may do too, depending on the circuit.